# ¿Cuál es el proposito de buildscript en Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

Estoy comenzando con gradle, y no me queda claro lo que he leído sobre esto.

Me queda la duda de la diferencia que hay entre el `bloque repositories` dentro del `bloque buildscript`, y el que está fuera del `bloque buildscript`.

Pregunto desde la ignorancia, ya que no he encontrado una respuesta a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

La sección de configuración "buildscript" es para gradle en sí (es decir, cambios en cómo gradle es capaz de realizar la compilación). Por lo tanto, esta sección suele incluir el complemento Android Gradle.

La sección "todos los proyectos" es para los módulos que está construyendo Gradle.

A menudo, la sección del repositorio es la misma para ambos, ya que ambos obtendrán sus dependencias de jcenter normalmente (o tal vez central de maven). Pero la sección de "dependencias" será diferente.

Normalmente la sección "dependencias" de "allprojects" está vacía ya que las dependencias para cada módulo son únicas y estarán en el archivo "build.gradle" dentro de cada uno de los módulos. Sin embargo, si todos los módulos compartieran las mismas dependencias, podrían enumerarse aquí.